# Outlook 2016 - integrate Appointment Creation with Web Applicaton

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-2016

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am working on a project that involves upgrading Outlook (2007) for my client to Outlook 2016. They have an add-in developed to perform a creation of a special type of appointment by using a web form. I do not have access to the code of that add-in.

My goal is to create a solution that:

1. would allow users to perform the same task with (ideally) identical user interface (considering outlook UI changes stylistically between 2007 and 2016).
2. integrates outlook with in-house web application.
3. pass the Outlook user to the web application for proper authorization (to be researched)

Opening a web page in the appointment creation screen is desirable as I have skills to make that page do and look like the way I want (I have web dev background).

I have done some research and found two resources that got me closer to making a decision, but I am still not sure if they both are capable of creating a solution.

- [Roadmap for Apps for Office, VSTO, and VBA (2013 article)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/18/roadmap-for-apps-for-office-vsto-and-vba/)
- [Outlook Technology Selection Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900714.aspx#OLSelectAPI_AdditionalResourcesAuxAPIs)

Outlook/office product team apparently decided to rename "Apps for office" that they introduced with office 2013 back into "add-ins", which makes research more confusing/complicated.
I could not find a similar stack overflow question.

Is there another way to look at the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all about the new Office Add-ins (as you remarked, yes they were renamed from Apps for Office a while back) at https://dev.office.com/.

For Outlooks specifically, you can find more details with references, how-to's and many more here: https://dev.outlook.com/

Comment: Thank you Philip.

Comment: The documentation there seems the most up to date and maintained as supposed the docs for old add-ins which are getting archived/not maintained any more.

I will try to use the new add-ins for as much as possible and will have to rollback to the old Add-ins for the features not yet supported.

It would be super-helpful to see extensibility comparison between old and new add-ins. I will link it here if I find one.